# Exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jboss

I get the following exception:

```
[0m[31m20/03/18 17:21:08,858 ERROR [fr.dsirc.tfront.security.CommonSecurityFilter] (ajp-/10.0.88.217:8109-5) Masquage de la cause réelle de l'exception en SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE : org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:106) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at fr.dsirc.tfront.security.CommonSecurityFilter.doFilter(CommonSecurityFilter.java:74) [tfront-ws-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:110) [cas-client-core-3.1.10.jar:]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169) [spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260) [spring-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.8.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.5.8.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:559) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:490) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:420) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
```

**Caused by:**

> ```
> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
>       at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:165)
> ```
>
> [hibernate-core-4.2.23.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.23.Final-redhat-1]
>             at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:286)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.23.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.23.Final-redhat-1]
>             at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
>   [hibernate-core-4.2.23.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.23.Final-redhat-1]
>             at fr.dsirc.sicor.core.entities.DonneesBcc_$$_jvst256_f.getDonnees(DonneesBcc_$$_jvst256_f.java)
>   [sicor-core-5.0.0-rc11.jar:]
>             at fr.dsirc.sicor.web.controllers.HomeController.recupEntetesScenarios(HomeController.java:865)
>   [classes:]

when I try to call from main the following lines:

```
for (Simulation s : listeSimulation) {
s.setCarriereBccAJour(true);
String carrieresJson = s.getDonneesBcc().getDonnees(); -- L865
```

with :

```
public DonneesBcc getDonneesBcc() {
    return donneesBcc;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "it_donnee_carriere_bcc")
private DonneesBcc donneesBcc;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "t_sic_donnee_carriere_bcc")
@TypeDefs( {@TypeDef( name= "StringJsonObject", typeClass = StringJsonUserType.class)})
public class DonneesBcc extends AbstractEntity {
```

and:

**getDonnees:**

```
public String getDonnees() {
    return donnees;
}
```

**the String donnees:**

```
@Column(name = "jo_contenu_carriere")
@Type(type = "StringJsonObject")
private String donnees;
```

**DonneesBcc**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "t_sic_donnee_carriere_bcc")
@TypeDefs( {@TypeDef( name= "StringJsonObject", typeClass = StringJsonUserType.class)})
public class DonneesBcc extends AbstractEntity {
```

Thanks for help